# How do I display an interactive map generated by the Google Maps API onto a Java application?

Tags: java, swing, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to display an interactive map in a JPanel using Swing, so I decided to use the Google Maps API, but I have no idea how to do it. I've looked at previous posts that have answered my question, but they are outdated solutions. Alternatively, if I can't embed it into my program, I have considered using the Mapbox API as well, but I run into the same problem of not knowing how to embed it into my program. Also important to note: I have to use IntelliJ IDEA, so I can't use other IDEs like Netbean to get this working. If anyone knows how to display an interactive map using through a JPanel without using JxBrowser, please let me know!

I've tried using JxBrowser's tutorial: https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/tutorials/maps.html but my license won't work for some reason. Whenever I run

`EngineOptions options = EngineOptions.newBuilder(HARDWARE_ACCELERATED).licenseKey("API_KEY").build();`

I end up getting an InvalidLicenseException even though I just got the license so I can't use the JxBrowser library for this. I have also tried using the JavaFX libraries. Admittedly, I am unfamiliar with how to use this library so I used code generated by ChatGPT, but it resulted in a blank screen:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GoogleMapsSwingExample extends JFrame {

    public GoogleMapsSwingExample() {
        super("Google Maps in Java Swing");

        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
        editorPane.setEditable(false);
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        // Enable debugging output
        editorPane.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, true);

        editorPane.setText("<html><body><iframe width=\"600\" height=\"450\" style=\"border: 0\" loading=\"lazy\" allowfullscreen " +
                "src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY&q=Eiffel%20Tower\" " +
                "onerror=\"alert('Failed to load Google Maps')\"></iframe></body></html>");

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GoogleMapsSwingExample example = new GoogleMapsSwingExample();
            example.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

I really have no idea what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [Java Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) but this requires extremely advanced Java coding and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The interactive map is essentially a web page. Unfortunately, whatever is built-in in Swing is not able to show a modern web page.

You have the following options:

1. Use [JCEF](https://github.com/JetBrains/jcef) (this is a link to JetBrain's fork, they have done a lot of work on it).
2. Use JavaFX and their WebView. The newer JavaFX version the better as they update the underlying WebKit engine every release.
3. Use SWT and its embedded browser. This control will use a browser provided by the operating system, therefore you may not get consistent a behaviour across different platforms. But they should be capable of displaying Google Maps.
4. Write to JxBrowser and figure out what went wrong with the license. We're always ready to help.